# Same Model3D does not seem equal each other?

Tags: c#, wpf, helix-3d-toolkit

I am loading STL files from a local file using HelixToolKit ModelImporter function. After loading Model3D I am store it in a dictionary as a key with value of file name.
My purpose of doing that I want to compare models for prevent loading same models.
After loading same model from same path it looks the dictionary for that models as a key. But it doesn't found like that model. Where am I going wrong, please help?

```
    private Model3D currModel = null;
    private string modelName = null;
    // A record of the 3D models we build.
    private Dictionary<Model3D, string> Models= new Dictionary<Model3D, string>();
    private Model3D device = null;     

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog open = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        if (open.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            try
            {
                string path = open.FileName;
                modelName = open.SafeFileName;

                currModel = display3D(path);

                if (!Models.ContainsKey(currModel))
                    Models.Add(currModel, modelName);
                ModelVisual3D device3D = new ModelVisual3D();
                device3D.Content = currModel;
                mainViewport.Children.Add(device3D);
                mainViewport.ZoomExtents();//modeli ekrana sığdırmak için
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error\n" + ex.Message.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }
    }
    private Model3D display3D(string path)
    {
        //Import 3D model file
        ModelImporter import = new ModelImporter();
        //Load the 3D model file
        device = import.Load(path);        
        return device;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update #1: Problem is solved. In my project ModelImporter does not load 3D Model; it loads 3DModelGroup. So if you add the Models.Children it works.

```
if (!Models.ContainsKey(currModel.Children))
        Models.Add(currModel.Children, modelName);
```

Answer (score 1):

The Dictionary class uses the GetHashCode method of the key to get a hash for the initial lookup in the dictionary.  It then uses the equals method of the key to determine if in fact the objects do match.  Each instance of the Model3d is returning either a different hash value or is deciding that the instances are not equal.  If you are only trying to determine if a model has been loaded before then consider using the full file path string as the key.  Otherwise, you may need to provide the dictionary a custom IEqualityComparer to override the behavior of the Model3d's default GetHashCode and Equals methods.  This url may help you understand the dictionary class better:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/500644/Understanding-Generic-Dictionary-in-depth